# Wie geht "statt + Personalpronomen" richtig?

Tags: grammatical-case

Es geht um einen Arbeitsplan, in dem mein Kollege Daniel eingetragen ist. An der Stelle sollte aber eigentlich mein Name stehen.

Möglichst kurz wollte ich das ausdrücken mit

> aufgrund eines Missverständnisses ist dort Daniel statt [...] eingetragen

Laut http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/statt_anstelle gehört dort ein Genitiv hin. Das wäre also

> aufgrund eines Missverständnisses ist dort Daniel statt meiner eingetragen

Klingt nicht unbedingt falsch, aber auch extrem ungewohnt, ist mir als Muttersprachler so gut wie nie untergekommen. Die anderen kurzen Varianten wie *an meiner statt* und *an meiner Stelle* (was wiederum eine Art "Anspruch" ausdrücken würde) sind nicht viel besser.

Ist *statt meiner* zumindest formal richtig?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Statt meiner" ist absolut natürlich und auch formal richtig.

Es ist ungewohnt, weil die meisten versuchen, so etwas zu umschreiben. In einem anderen Forum habe ich sogar die Aussage gefunden, dass das kein Deutsch wäre. Weit verfehlt. Eine anderweitige Formulierung wie zum Beispiel

> Anstatt Daniels Namen hätte meiner dort stehen sollen.

klingt mit Sicherheit für jedermann vertrauter. Hier handelt es sich übrigens um ein Possessivpronomen (in nicht attributiver Form).

Aber auch eine kleine Änderung an deinem Satz könnte ihn 'besser' klingen lassen, und zwar indem du "meiner" nicht mehr alleine stehen lässt (entspricht dann auch dem Possessivpronomen, jedoch in attributiver Form und somit auch Possessivartikel genannt):

> aufgrund eines Missverständnisses ist dort Daniel anstatt meiner Wenigkeit eingetragen

Wie dem auch sei. Es gibt mit Sicherheit viele Alternativen, aber ich sehe kein Problem mit der schlichten Verwendung von "meiner". Persönlich finde ich das übrigens besser als "an meiner statt", was noch unüblicher ist.

Und um dich daran ein wenig zu gewöhnen, lies doch mal [diesen Text](http://nextz.de/glossen/meiner-statt.htm).

Comment: Vielleicht sollten wir noch darauf hinweisen, dass in der Frage dem Personalpronomen *meiner* der Bezug fehlt. Du hast das hier mit "Daniels **Namen**" und mit "Wenigkeit" gut gelöst.

Comment: @Takkat Bin mir nicht sicher, ob ich dem so ganz zustimme. Bekanntlich ersetzt ein Personalpronomen ein bereits genanntes Nomen. Auch wenn "meine Wenigkeit" nicht explizit genannt wurde, so ist "ich", "meiner", "mir" und "mich" immer verständlich. In meiner Variation mit dem Namen ersetzt "meiner" nur den Namen anstatt meiner Person. In "meiner Wenigkeit" ist es kein Personalpronomen mehr. Ich bin mir nicht ganz sicher, aber müsse das da nicht ein Possessivpronomen sein?

Comment: Du hast natürlich recht, es war ein Vertipper, ich meinte **Possesivpronomen**, nicht Personalpronomen in obigem Kommentar, und dem fehlt dann der Bezug.

Comment: "Meiner" kommt hier zweimal als Possesivpronomen vor (einmal begleitend und einmal stellvertretend), wobei es aber genauso gut auch als alleinstehendes Personalpronomen vorkommen könnte: "Daniel (an)statt meiner"/"Daniel an meiner statt".